# Get even numbers with composition

Tags: f#

I can obtain the even numbers in a list using the lambda syntax:

```
[1..10] |> List.filter (fun x -> x % 2 = 0)
```

But I want get it with composition, like this:

```
[1..10] |> List.filter ((% 2) >> (= 0))
```

Error: stdin(7,37): error FS0010: Unexpected integer literal in expression. Expected ')' or other token.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

F# does not support [operator sections](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator). You can partially apply an operator by enclosing it in parentheses, like so:

```
let five = (+) 2 3
let add2 = (+) 2
let alsoFive = add2 3
```

However, this will not allow you to partially apply the *right* argument of the operator. In other words, F# does not offer anything equivalent to Haskell expression `(/ 2)`. This can be worked around for commutative operators, such as addition or multiplication, because `(+ 2) === (2 +)`, which in F# can be expressed as `((+) 2)`, but not for non-commutative ones.

The best you can do is declare the section as a separate function, like this:

```
let mod2 x = x % 2
[1..10] |> List.filter (mod2 >> ((=) 0))
```

If you absolutely insist on not declaring any more functions, you could try to do with a `flip`:

```
[1..10] |> List.filter ((flip (%) 2) >> ((=) 0))
```

But sadly, F# standard library does not provide a `flip` function either, so you'd have to declare it yourself anyway:

```
let inline flip f a b = f b a
```

Personally, I would rather go for increased readability and declare an `isEven` function:

```
let isEven x = (x % 2) = 0
[1..10] |> List.filter isEven
```

Comment: [FSharpx.Extras](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras) has `flip` I think.

Comment: Adding a dependency or declaring yourself - same amount of work. If you have a dozen of these, maybe go for dependency. But for just one - too much.